# check if two columns have a one-to-one relationship in R

Tags: r

Is there any existing R functionality to check if two columns have a one-to-one relationship (regardless of column type).

Example of expected output:

```
A    B     C
0    'a'   'apple'
1    'b'   'banana'
2    'c'   'apple'
```

A & B are one-to-one? TRUE

A & C are one-to-one? FALSE

B & C are one-to-one? FALSE

Comment: Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52399474/6152316

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you `match` a vector to itself it will return an integer vector giving the first index each unique value occurs at. We can compare these integer vectors directly:

```
is_one_to_one = function(x, y) {
  xu = match(x, x)
  yu = match(y, y)
  identical(xy, yu)
}
```

You could then apply this to each pair of columns.

Wrapping it up in a function:

```
cor_1to1 = function(df) {
  mat = vapply(df, \(x) match(x, x), FUN.VALUE = integer(nrow(df)))
  nm = combn(colnames(mat), m = 2, FUN = paste, collapse = " :: ")
  val = combn(colnames(mat), m = 2, FUN = function(i) {
      identical(mat[, i[1]], mat[, i[2]])
    }, simplify = TRUE)
  setNames(val, nm)
}

# A :: B A :: C B :: C 
#   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
```

Comment: Excellent work!

Answer (score 3):

### Use the `mappings` function in the `utilities` package

*(Note: This is a copy of other answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397799/397842#397842) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399474/) to essentially the same question on CV.SE.)*

You can examine functional mappings between variables in a data-frame using the `mappings` function in the [`utilities` package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/utilities/index.html) in `R`.  This function takes an input data-frame and examines whether there are mappings between the variables.  By default the function examines only the factor variables, but you can examine all variables in the data by setting `all.vars = TRUE`.  (Bear in mind that mappings between non-factor variables should be interpreted with caution; continuous variables are almost always in a one-to-one mapping because they do not have duplicate values.)  Here is an example of a mock dataset containing five factor variables, with a number of mappings between them.

```
#Create data frame 
VAR1 <- c(0,1,2,2,0,1,2,0,0,1)
VAR2 <- c('A','B','B','B','A','B','B','A','A','B')
VAR3 <- c(1:10)
VAR4 <- c('A','B','C','D','A','B','D','A','A','B')
VAR5 <- c(1:5,1:5)
DATA <- data.frame(VAR1 = factor(VAR1),
                   VAR2 = factor(VAR2),
                   VAR3 = factor(VAR3),
                   VAR4 = factor(VAR4),
                   VAR5 = factor(VAR5))
DATA

   VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5
1     0    A    1    A    1
2     1    B    2    B    2
3     2    B    3    C    3
4     2    B    4    D    4
5     0    A    5    A    5
6     1    B    6    B    1
7     2    B    7    D    2
8     0    A    8    A    3
9     0    A    9    A    4
10    1    B   10    B    5
```

We can examine the mappings using the `R` code below.  As you can see, the output of the function shows you all the functional relationships that hold between the factors, and it also tells you which factors are "redundant" (i.e., functions of other factors).  By default the output includes a DAG plot showing the mappings between the factors.

```
#Examine mappings in the data
library(utilities)
MAPS <- mappings(DATA)
MAPS


Mapping analysis for data-frame DATA containing 5 factors (analysis ignores NA values) 

There were 7 mappings identified: 
 
     VAR1 → VAR2 
     VAR3 → VAR1 
     VAR3 → VAR2 
     VAR3 → VAR4 
     VAR3 → VAR5 
     VAR4 → VAR1 
     VAR4 → VAR2 

Redundant factors: 
 
     VAR1 
     VAR2 
     VAR4 
     VAR5 

Non-Redundant factors: 
 
     VAR3
```

[image]

As can be seen from the output and the plot, the only non-redundant factor in the data-frame is `VAR3`; all other factor variables are functions of this variable.  (This can also be confirmed by looking at the values in the data-frame.)

Comment: Vote to close the question as a duplicate, don't post the same answer to multiple questions.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't yet have sufficient rep to vote to close questions, but happy for you to flag as duplicate.

Comment: You can still flag the question as duplicate if you don't have the rep to vote for closure. It will be sent to the queues to be handled there.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```r
one_to_one <- function(data){
  data[] <- sapply(data, \(x) match(x, x))
  pairs <- t(combn(seq_len(ncol(data)), 2))
  
  cbind(t(matrix(colnames(data)[t(pairs)], nrow = 2)),
        One2One = apply(pairs, 1, function(x) all(Reduce(`==`, data[, x])))) |>
    as.data.frame()
}
```

test

```r
one_to_one(df)
#  V1 V2 One2One
#1  A  B    TRUE
#2  A  C   FALSE
#3  B  C   FALSE
```

Comment: I was just comparing and noticed your edit -- both `match(x, x)` and `match(x, unique(x))` work. `unique()` slows things down a tiny bit (only noticeably on huge data), but keeps the the values "dense" in the integers. `match(x, x)` is a little speedier, but the integer values will be the first index at which a value occurred. Test on `x = c(1, 1, 2, 3)` to see.  In this case, either one works.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful solution. This link suggests I accept one answer, so I'll  accept @GregorThomas because it has a little more explanation. https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/12/01/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer/#:~:text=It%27s%20generally%20considered%20good%20etiquette,there%20are%20certainly%20valid%20exceptions.)